# running time upper bound for b-tree

Tags: algorithm, b-tree, taocp

In *the Art of Computer Programming*, on the bottom of page 485

> Suppose there's a B-tree of order m, and there are N keys, so the N+1 leaves appear on level l.
>
> The numbers of nodes on levels 1,2,3... is at least 2,2[m/2],2[m/2]^2...

(Here [] denotes upper bound)

And Knuth give

> N+1 >= 2[m/2]^(l-1)

---

My question is:

Shouldn't this be N+1 >= 2+2[m/2]+2[m/2]^2+...+2[m/2]^(l-1)?

What's the point of only taking nodes of the (l-1)th level into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A branch node with *k* keys has *k* + 1 children.  So however many nodes there are on level *l* - 1, there must be more nodes on level *l*.

So *N* + 1 (the number of nodes on level *l*) is greater than the number of nodes on level *l* - 1.  Obviously the actual number of nodes on level *l* - 1 is greater than or equal to the *minimum* number of nodes on level *l* - 1.  So *N* + 1 ≥ 2⌈*m* / 2⌉<sup>*l* - 1</sup>.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when will N + 1 = 2⌈m / 2⌉l - 1 happen?